# Javascript: Form validation is causing a selected Ajax Live Search field to be reset to Null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

From the first screenshot below, I have a Flask app that has a search field that use Ajax request to query a list of US States to return as dropdown values. When I leave the `Name` field empty and hit Submit, this is inadvertently removing the dropdown value I had earlier selected. I want to retain the dropdown field during form validation as well.

[image]
[image]

**app.py**

```
import sys

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from forms import InputForm

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "Development"

US_STATES = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa", "Arizona", "California",
             "Colorado", "Connecticut", "District ", "of Columbia", "Delaware",
             "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois",
             "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Massachusetts", "Maryland",
             "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi", "Montana",
             "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire",
             "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "Nevada", "New York", "Ohio", "Oklahoma",
             "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina",
             "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Virgin Islands",
             "Vermont", "Washington", "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming"]

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():

    form = InputForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(form.name.data, file=sys.stderr)
        print(form.states.data, file=sys.stderr)
        print(form.territory.data, file=sys.stderr)
        print("Hello from outside Validate.", file=sys.stderr)

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            print(form.name.data, file=sys.stderr)
            print(form.states.data, file=sys.stderr)
            print(form.territory.data, file=sys.stderr)
            print("Hello from inside Validate.", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    return render_template("states.html", form=form)


@app.route("/search")
def search():
    text = request.args["searchText"]

    result = [c for c in US_STATES if text.lower() in c.lower()]
    return {"results": result}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=5001, debug=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms import validators
from wtforms.validators import Optional, InputRequired, DataRequired

class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    states = SelectField("US States", validate_choice=False)
    territory = SelectField("Is Territory?", choices=["Unknown", "Yes", "No"], default="Unknown", validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Add State", validators=[Optional()])
```

**templates\index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Live Search Ajax Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function liveSearch(value) {
        value = value.trim();
        if (value != "") {
          $.ajax({
            url: "search",
            data: { searchText: value },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              var res = "";
              for (i in data.results) {
                res += "<option value=" + data.results[i] + ">" + data.results[i] + "</option>";
              }
              $("#states").html(res);
            },
          });
        } else {
          $("#states").html("");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- Main -->
      <main role="main" class="container">
        <div>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**templates\states.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
      <h2>Live Search in Flask with Ajax</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
      <form method="POST" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              {{ form.name.label(class="form-control-label") }}
              {% if form.name.errors %}
                  {{ form.name(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ form.name(class="form-control form-control-md") }}
              {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              {{ form.territory.label(class="form-control-label") }}
              {% if form.territory.errors %}
                  {{ form.territory(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in form.territory.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ form.territory(class="form-control form-select") }}
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group mt-4 mb-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search USA States" onkeyup="liveSearch(this.value)">
                {{ form.states(class="form-control form-select") }}
              </input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3 justify-content-md-end">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary btn-sm") }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>        
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: So stop wiping it out? `else {
          $("#states").html("");
        }`  Am I missing some other key piece of information here?

Comment: Hey Mark, I tried removing that out, but still it will be wiped out during form validation. Any ideas? All the code required to run the project is up there.

Comment: In your server-side validation you should put that list in the select as options OR trigger the ajax function on page load to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I tried adding `$(document).ready(function(){` at the start of the function, but it seems to be not working. I am new to Javascript, so it will be great help if you can share an edited code from above. Thanks again.

Comment: I would also like to add that the list is just an example, and that my other code has to query via API to a list containing 10,000+ rows and more added daily. So, preloading the list will not be a good option in this case.

Comment: Did you tried with localStorage ?

Comment: Hey Swati, I know localStorage can work, but it seems like a hassle to write that much code to correct a behavior. I am new to Ajax, so I would like to find out a straight forward solution. Is localStorage the only option left?

Comment: If you can bring back value of atleast search input and select-box selected value then you can trigger your ajax call onload and fill your dropdown options.

Comment: can you pls explain what you're expecting, because I see everything as expected, I'm trying to write a piece of code but I don't really understand what are you attempting to do. PS: I think you have a problem with the JQuery code logic.

Answer (score 1):

The [JQuery official documentation](https://jquery.com/) is very beginner-friendly if you need something, I suggest you to start from there.
Otherwise explain clearly what are you attempting to do.
Here is a cleaner way to do what you have already done.

Make sur that your form content has a pretty strict rules (I think you can customize this on your "form builder" in the backend) like for example :

```
<input name="Name" type="text" maxlength="10" required />
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputSearchStates').keyup(function () { // when a keyboard key is hitted (even CTRL is included and all keyboard keys...)
        var value = $(this).val().trim(); // remove first and last blank spaces from your string (note that blank spaces in the middle will still remain)
        if (this.form.reportValidity()) { // return true if the form is valid (required inputs already filled ...etc)
            $.ajax({
                url: "search",
                data: {
                    searchText: value
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    // data is the returned result from your backend
                    // it can be a string/filled array/empty array/number/float ...etc
                    $("#states").empty(); // always make your dropdown empty (with definitely no options to select)

                    data.results.each(function () { // automatically fetch the response result (a JS array) if exists , else it will do nothing.
                        $("#states").append(`
                                <option value="${this}"> ${this} </option>
                        `); // for each available data in your response result and append <options> respectively
                    });

                    // remember that your dropdown will still empty if no data there is no data in your response array.
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explaining the concept clearly, Hicham. I have the functionality working as expected with the script, but with one small issue. 

Imagine I have 50 fields (similar to `Name` in the screenshot) and each of them having its own validation. After filling up those 50 fields, and the user selecting a `State` from the dropdown, when they will proceed to `Submit` the form, there is a high likelihood of a validation error. In this case, I want to retain what the user has already selected as the `State`, because if they don't the form will be submitted with an empty `State`.

Comment: I have listed example of only one `State` field, but my actual form has six of these dropdowns and they are related to selecting `Contact` information from a list of 10,000+ contacts. You can now imagine how important it is to retain the dropdown information before validation, and not force the user to select the information all over again.

Comment: You welcome @Shantanu we're here to help each other. As I know if the form validation failed, the form will not get submited .. I don't really undertand why the form get submit and then became "empty" after clicking on the submit button. are you using a custome jquery validation pluggin or something like that ..?

Comment: No, the whole code to execute the project is right there. This is a simple Flask project, so you can install Python and Flask and verify it yourself about this behavior. Most of it has to do with the JQuery though that is already up there.

Comment: @Shantanu I have edited my answer .. would you check if it's valaible for you